# Tomcat shows old version of txt file, deleted work directory, restarted, checked... it's still old file

Tags: tomcat

```
root@condor1796 /home/glassfish/apache-tomcat-8.5.5 # find . | grep "ads.txt" | xargs ls -l
-rw-r----- 1 glassfish nogroup 18892 Apr 24  2020 ./appBaseLivingCost/ROOT/ads.txt
-rw-r----- 1 glassfish nogroup 18892 Apr 24  2020 ./appBaseNonWwwNumbeo/ROOT/ads.txt
root@condor1796 /home/glassfish/apache-tomcat-8.5.5 # unzip -v appBaseNonWwwNumbeo/ROOT.war | grep "ads.txt"
   18892  Stored    18892   0% 2020-04-24 16:13 dae45795  ads.txt
```

From server.xml:

```
  <Host name="numbeo.com"  appBase="appBaseNonWwwNumbeo"
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Alias>numbeo.com</Alias>
```

Removed work directory.

I did kill Catalina and started it again.

The server still serves the old file (which is not 18892 bytes).

I'm totally confused. What happened?

Tomcat version 8.5.5

Answer (score 0):

Lame!

It turned out that I have

```
@WebServlet(name = "AdsTxt", urlPatterns = {"/ads.txt"})
```

Removed that AdsTxt servlet and now it works.

LOL!!!!